# How to set browser specific css in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How to set style `-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 11px #000` to an element via JavaScript?

Answer (score 6):

You can set it using the `style` object:

```
element.style['-webkit-box-shadow'] = '0px 0px 11px #000';
```

Demo: [jsfiddle.net/S2eLb/](http://jsfiddle.net/S2eLb/)

#### Edit:

To be clear, this method does *not* require the jQuery library.

Answer (score 1):

Since I haven't yet seen a code example that works without jQuery, here's one:

```
document.getElementById("test").style.webkitBoxShadow = "0px 0px 11px #000";
```

Note that the javascript property is not the same as the CSS property.  The javascript properties do not use a dash and use camelCase instead.

And, a working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/4LT7u/

Comment: You are mistaken. My answer doesn't use jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .css

```
$("divClass").css("-webkit-box-shadow","0px 0px 11px #000");
```

Links: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#elementname').css({
        '-webkit-box-shadow':'0px 0px 11px #000'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CamelCase like this:

```
WebkitBoxShadow
```

Generally, a `-<lowerCaseLetter>` translates to the corresponding uppercase letter in the JS API.